# Ubuntu Server 18.04.01 LTS CIFS Mount failing

Tags: mount, samba, virtualization, fstab, cifs

Having issues getting my persistent network shares to mount in Ubuntu, here is what ive added to /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.2.10/AlphaData_GlobalShare  /media/AlphaData  cifs  credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1001,gid=1001,vers=3.0,sec=ntlm  0  0
//192.168.2.10/AlphaMedia_GlobalShare  /media/AlphaMedia  cifs  credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1001,gid=1001,vers=3.0,sec=ntlm  0  0
//192.168.2.10/VMRoot_GlobalShare  /media/VMRoot  cifs 
credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1001,gid=1001,vers=3.0,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

Here is the error i get for sudo mount -a

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

And here are the logs

```
Oct 20 09:49:20 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2150.545771] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
Oct 20 09:52:55 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2365.006778] CIFS VFS: Unable to select appropriate authentication method!
Oct 20 09:52:55 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2365.006780] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -22
Oct 20 09:52:55 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2365.007569] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
Oct 20 09:53:00 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2370.037292] CIFS VFS: Unable to select appropriate authentication method!
Oct 20 09:53:00 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2370.037294] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -22
Oct 20 09:53:00 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2370.038419] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
Oct 20 09:53:05 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2375.077100] CIFS VFS: Unable to select appropriate authentication method!
Oct 20 09:53:05 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2375.077102] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -22
Oct 20 09:53:05 ubuntudocker kernel: [ 2375.078377] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

Not sure whats causing the issues here, the shares are hosted on a FreeNAS 11.2-RC1 server, same with the Ubuntu Server VM. Any idea whats causing the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Remove `sec=ntlm`. That hasn't worked for a few versions now, but it's still in lots of tutorials around the interwebs.

Comment: seems that removing sec=ntlm worked, its mounted properly, the issue ive now got is that when I try and make a directory its saying permission denied unless I use sudo mkdir. The mount details are the same as the ones I log in with on my windows machine which doesnt have any issues making directories. Any ideas? I feel like this is me being stupid on this one

Comment: I struggled with this problem and I'm not sure I found the right answer. I made myself the owner of the directory that the share gets mounted into.  I had a lot of trouble with ownership and permissions when I started setting up shares.  It might be worth asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that `sec=ntlm` no longer works. That setting is inconsistent with the version of the samba dialect you are using however.

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 Samba server set up. If I try to mount with your settings:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //gort.local/Public /home/morbius/Test -o guest,vers=3.0,sec=ntlm
```

It fails with the exact "Invalid argument" error message and logs the exact same errors.

If instead I run the mount command with a version of the smb dialect consistent with that security setting:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //gort.local/Public /home/morbius/Test -o guest,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm
```

It does work:

> mount | grep cifs
>
> //gort.local/Public on /home/morbius/Test type cifs
>   (rw,relatime,**vers=1.0,sec=ntlm**,cache=strict ....

If you want to connect to the server with sec=ntlm change to vers=1.0 - I don't know why you would want or need to do that but .....

Or keep vers=3.0 and drop sec=ntlm in which case sec defaults to ntlmssp which is consistant with SMBv3.

Comment: seems that removing sec=ntlm worked, its mounted properly, the issue ive now got is that when I try and make a directory its saying permission denied unless I use sudo mkdir. The mount details are the same as the ones I log in with on my windows machine which doesnt have any issues making directories. Any ideas? I feel like this is me being stupid on this one

Comment: Add another option to your fstab declaration: nounix as in //192.168.2.10/AlphaData_GlobalShare  /media/AlphaData  cifs  credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1001,gid=1001,vers=3.0,nounix  0  0