# How do I permanently mount a windows network share in Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, fstab, smb

I'm trying to figure out how to permanently mount a windows network share in Ubuntu. Can anyone help me with the required steps?

Comment: ask ubuntu is a Q&A site. I’m voting to close this because it's not a question.

Comment: @chicocr you should edit the question, and separate the question from answer. Then post your own answer, and accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change permissions on mounted windows share?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393563/how-to-change-permissions-on-mounted-windows-share)

Answer (score 9):

I spent countless hours and visited numerous webpages to what I thought would be a straight forward problem.  After writing up my notes for future reference, I decided to post them here to help anyone who might have similar problems.  The notes have gone thru a few revisions and for reference there are 4 sources for further reading.

This solution has been installed and working on three ubuntu VM’s that are running under Windows 10 Pro Hyper-V and Ubuntu 20.04 KVM VMM.  So far the network shares popup quickly and there is no appreciable lag times when traveling up and down the directory trees.

This solution solves a similar problem in Hyper-V when using ‘passthrough hard drives’; the Ubuntu vm's have only ‘read’ permissions on the hard drives.  Unfortunately, Microsoft discourages using passthrough hard drives and this caused me to look for a linux solution.  The hard drives are needed since they are to be used for extensive i/o.  In my experience hard drives have faster write speeds and usually last longer than ssd drives.

Installation Notes:

1. The steps below have the mount points in the ‘/media/‘ folder, this follows what was recommended on some source webpages.  When I started to solve this problem my mount points were setup in the ‘/mnt/‘ folder, as of now I am not sure if that will still work. You could give it a try if that’s what you want.
2. xrdp, which enables remote desktop access to a ubuntu-pc, was used in all my installations.  If you do not need this capability omit this package from the first step; everything else should still work.
3. All the steps listed are what I actually used.

——————————————————————————————————————————

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Source: https://www.techjunkie.com/automatically-mount-network-shares-linux/

Source: [How to change permissions on mounted windows share?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393563/how-to-change-permissions-on-mounted-windows-share)

Source: [Ubuntu Server 18.04.01 LTS CIFS Mount failing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085692/ubuntu-server-18-04-01-lts-cifs-mount-failing)
——————————————————————————————————————————

### after new Ubuntu install, additional packages to add:

xrdp, samba-common, samba, smbclient

### open ‘Terminal’ and enter the following commands:

#### install cifs utilities

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

#### create mount points for windows shares and set permissions

```
sudo mkdir /media/mountName

sudo chown userId:userId /media/mountName

sudo chmod 755 /media/mountName
```

#### create ‘credentials’ file to hold userid/password and set permissions

```
sudo nano ~/.smbcredentials
```

#### enter the following 2 lines

```
username=windowsLoginId
password=windowsPassword
```

enter 'ctrl-x', then 'y' and finally 'enter' to exit and save file

#### set permissions to hide username and password

```
sudo chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials
```

#### retrieve ‘uid’ and ‘gid’ values for next step

id

the ‘id’ command will output something similar to the following:

```
uid=1000(userId) gid=1000(userId) groups=1000(userId),4(adm),………….,1001(smbgroup)
```

#### backup and edit ‘fstab’ to mount window share at ubuntu startup

```
mkdir ~/system-backups

cp /etc/fstab ~/system-backups

sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

at end of file enter the following line:

```
//winServerName/shareName /media/mountName cifs credentials=/home/userId/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.0,nounix  0   0
```

(Note: for the last 2 ‘0’ enter a ‘tab’ before the ‘0’ and delete any carriage returns)

enter 'ctrl-x', then 'y' and finally 'enter' to exit and save file

#### test mounting of windows network share

```
sudo mount -a
```

if no errors appear, the mount should appear in ‘file manager’

check mount in file manager for read/write access

#### test permanent network share

shutdown and reboot pc

open ‘file manager’ and check network share

#### other relevant commands

manually mount network share

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=windowsLoginId //winServerName/shareName /media/mountName
```

you will be prompted for the ‘password’

prepare mount point for deletion; do not run command where ‘pwd’ is ‘/media’

```
sudo umount /media/mountName
```

delete mount point

```
rmdir /media/mountName
```

Comment: I do this all the time. What's xrdp for? It seems unnecessary, at least I don't have it installed. Also cifs-utils pulls in samba, so if you install it first, you save a step.

Comment: 1) In my research I came across a lot of answers but none worked for me; my solution was put together from various articles.  2) I am using xrdp for 'remote desktop' access. I have multiple pc's (windows, mac's and ubuntu) and vm's on my home network and I can login to all these machines from my main desktop pc.  3) Thanks for the tip on cifs-utils.

Comment: Good info, but xrdp has nothing to do with mounting shares with samba, so it doesn't belong in these instructions AFAIK

Comment: @chicocr since the question and answer both belongs to you, and the answer working for you, you should "accept" the answer by clicking little tick right underneath "vote arrows". Thanks.

Comment: I was able to use this successfully on Ubunut 20.04 LTS - However `//WinServerName/shareName` did not work. I was able to use `//192.168.x.x/shareName` instead (static local IP).

Comment: You only need `cifs-utils` unless its all old windows/ubuntu. Try cifs and if that does not work then use `smb` CIFS worked fine for me from 20.0 onwards with windows 10 and above.